# Yatzy, how do I refer to my Player-attributes?

Tags: python

I have a huge problem right now, I cannot refer to my Player-attributes, my code is looking like this currently:

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.ones=0
        self.twos=0
        self.threes=0
        self.fours=0
        self.fives=0
        self.sixs=0
        self.abovesum=0
        self.bonus=0
        self.onepair=0
        self.twopair=0
        self.threepair=0
        self.fourpair=0
        self.smalladder=0
        self.bigladder=0
        self.house=0
        self.chance=0
        self.yatzy=0
        self.totalsum=0
        #self.lista={"ones":0,"twos":0,"threes":0, "fours":0,"fives":0,"sixs":0,"abovesum":0,"bonus":0,"onepair":0,"twopair":0,"threepair":0,"fourpair":0,"smalladder":0,"bigladder":0,"house":0,"chance":0,"yatzy":0,"totalsum":0}

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def countbonus(self):
        self.abovesum=self.ones+self.twos+self.threes+self.fours+self.fives+self.sixs
        if self.abovesum>=63:
            self.bonus+=50
            return self.abovesum, self.bonus
        else:
            return self.abovesum, self.bonus

    def counttotalsum(self):
        self.totalsum=self.abovesum+self.bonus+self.onepair+self.twopair+self.threepair+self.fourpair+self.smalladder+self.bigladder+self.house+self.chance+self.yatzy

    def add(self):
        moment=input("Where do you want to put your points?: ")  #ej klar
        points=input("How many points did you get?: ")
        self.lista

    def visa(self):
        for i in self.name:
            print(i)

def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
    players = int(input("How many players: "))
    rounds=0
    spelarlista=[]
    spelarlista.append("name")
    while not players==rounds:
        player=input("What is your name?: ")
        rounds=rounds+1
        spelarlista.append(Player(player))
    table_data = [spelarlista,
        ['Ettor',spelarlista[0].ones],
        ['Tvåor'],
        ['Treor'],
        ['Fyror'],
        ['femmor'],
        ['sexor']]
    table = AsciiTable(table_data)
    table.inner_row_border = True
    table.table_data[0][0] += '\n'
    print(table.table)
welcome()
```

I'm currently getting the errormessage "Str"-object has no attribute "ones". I understand that the line spelarlista[0].ones is not working, but let's say I ru the programme with the players "James" and "Anders", and I want my yatzy to print out the table with the players current score, how do I refer to that, let's say I did type "James" first, what do I write to get his points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tjena Joakim! Svenska är najs men när det kommer till programmering är det bra att hålla sig till endast ett språk (vilket oftast är engelska). Även om du bara programmerar för dig själv för närvarande kan det vara en bra rutin att försöka träna in då det underlättar för andra programmerare att läsa din kod och att hjälpa dig. Om du är intresserad av jobb inom programmering måste det ju också vara skriven på engelska. **English summary: It's often better to use only english in your code.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spelarlista.append("name")` means that the first item in your list is a string. Then later you try to access `spelarlista[0].ones`.

As the error message says, string objects do not have an attribute `ones`.

Comment: Thanks you, sometimes you can get blind when watching your own code!

Comment: If this fixes your problem please accept my answer with the tick button :)

Comment: There you go! I actually have another question if you got time.... Now that I can refer to the players, I need to refer to every player, so I have to go like spelarlista[1].ones, spelarlista[2].ones, but only as many times as I got  
players. Let's say I type the names "James","Peter" and "Alfred". Is there a way to make my programme smart enough to realize that there is 3 players and refer to the different players score in my board?

Comment: If I understand you, you're looking for a "for loop". It's hard to explain much in comments but that will let you iterate over a list of names or players, and do something with each.

Comment: Exactly, but the problem is that I have Asciitable (it was the best solution I could find for printing a board). So, when I go with like "Peter","James" and "Alfred", I get three columns + the name column. Now I need to make sure that I also print the three players score downbelow, but I'm unsure how I do this with asciitable...

Comment: What would solve my problem is to make each row in the ascii-table a header row, but that might be impossible?

Comment: I don't know anything about asciitable. It might be worth opening another question, specifically about the asciitable part of this problem.

Comment: @JoakimDahl Submit your question to CodeReview (if your code is working but you want to improve it) and you might get the answers you need. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/